# Google App Engine and Amazon Web Services

Tags: asp.net, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services

I have an ASP.Net Web Application with SQL Server as Back end. Even though I use my machine, My code should be installed on distributed machines. So, I need to use any of Google App Engine or Amazon Web Services to do this.

I want to know Is there any suport for ASP.Net Web applications in AWS or GAE which is easier to stat with etc..

Kindly spot few materials with examples which might be of some help for starters like me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Unless something has changed recently on AppEngine, I don't think you can host asp.net applications there.

AWS and Azure would both be viable options for cloud asp.net solutions. I prefer AWS myself, but obviously with Microsoft behind Azure, their asp.net support/offerings will be top notch as well.

Comment: Yes things have changed. This answer no longer applies

Comment: @ZigMandel: can you post a link to asp.net on appengine? I couldn't find any after a quick look.

Comment: Not on appengine. On gce (which is the only thing comparable to aws) you can use windows and install asp

Answer (score 0):

Google appengine is not comparable with aws. One is infrastructure the other is platform. You can only compare aws with google compute engine (gce).
Both can run windows and install anything you want on them. (Gce just announced support for windows this month)